# On that one , though

Tags: phrase-usage

The following took place in a board of trustees meeting :

> **Speaker 1 :** The college has always based its legislative initiatives on local control, and this kind of articulates that .If
>   you see something here, feel free to provide some  insights.
>
> **Speaker 2 :** Thank you. Definitely a working document. Not complete. Second one is related to the partnerships with KBOR. We
>   tried to state our position and then why.
>   **On that one, though,** we need to probably explain what Senate Bill 345 is. Most readers won't know. That needs to be better explained. It's a 100-plus page legislation.

What does **"on that one ,though"** mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"... on that one though..." means "... about that subject, though ...", or "... as to that matter ...".

It is referring to "... second one...", that is, the second subject, the partnerships with KBOR, that has been brought up by Speaker 2.

This material may remain difficult to understand because it is a transcription of speech between speakers who know each other and their subjects.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: I wonder if it was used informally in that context... could you please clarify in which context it can be used ?

Comment: It can be used when a subject has just been raised, and one wants to say something about it without describing it again. You ask whether it is informal; yes, of course it is, since it is spontaneous undedited speech, not writing.

Comment: many thanks for your help